# ¿Porqué getElementsByClassName no se puede combinar con getElementsByTagName?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy aprendiendo a usar JavaScript y me agarro una curiosidad y tengo entendido que puedo buscar los elementos según un determinado TagName dentro de elementos de un determinado ID.
Pero porque no puedo buscar ciertos TagName según un ClassName. Les dejo el código HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Blog de Viajes</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">

  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
        <div class="contenedor">
            <div id="logo" class="logo">
                <img src="img/logo.png">
            </div> <!--.logo-->

            <div class="buscador">
              <form class="formulario" action="index.html" method="post">
                    <label for="buscador">
                        <input type="search" id="buscador" name="buscador" placeholder="Buscar">
                    </label>
                    <input type="submit" id="buscar" class="buscador" value="Buscar">
              </form>
            </div>
        </div> <!--.contenedor-->
    </header>
    <div id="navegacion" class="navegacion">
        <nav id="menu">
            <ul class="clearfix">
                <li><a target="_blank" href="#">Inicio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Nosotros</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Mision</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Vision</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Valores</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Consejos</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Ciudades</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Promociones</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Tienda</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <div id="contenido" class="contenido">
        <main>
            <article>
                <h2>Viajar a Londres</h2>
                <img src="img/imagen_1.jpg" alt="visitar londres">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                <a href="#" class="boton">Leer más</a>
            </article>
            <article>
                <h2>Puente de la Torre</h2>
                <img src="img/imagen_2.jpg" alt="puente de la torre">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                <a href="#" class="boton">Leer más</a>
            </article>
            <article>
                <h2>Metro de Londres</h2>
                <img src="img/imagen_3.jpg" alt="metro de londres">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                <a href="#" class="boton">Leer más</a>
            </article>
        </main>

        <aside id="sidebar" class="sidebar">
            <h2>Otros posts</h2>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Entrada 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Entrada 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Entrada 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Entrada 4</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Entrada 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </aside>
    </div> <!--contenido-->


    <footer>

      <div class="contenedor">
          <div class="nosotros">
              <h2>Sobre nosotros</h2>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
              </p>
          </div>
          <div class="menu navegacion">
            <h2>Menú de navegación</h2>
            <nav>
              <a href="#">Inicio</a>
              <a href="#">Nosotros</a>
              <a href="#">Blog</a>
              <a href="#">Tienda</a>
              <a href="#">Contacto</a>
            </nav>
          </div>
      </div>

      <p class="copyright">
          Todos los derechos reservados &copy;. Blog de Viajes 2016
      </p>
    </footer>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Y acá el código JavaScript:

```
(function(){
  'use strict';
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

        var enlaces = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
        console.log(enlaces);

        for(var i = 0; i < enlaces.length; i++){
          enlaces[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank');
        }

        var enlacesSidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar').getElementsByTagName('a');
        console.log(enlacesSidebar);

  });

})();
```

Estando así funciona perfectamente y por consola me sale lo siguiente:

> HTMLCollection(5) [a, a, a, a, a]

Pero si yo cambio la línea de enlancesSidebar código por:

```
var enlacesSidebar = document.getElementsByClassName('sidebar').getElementsByTagName('a');
```

en consola me sale el siguiente error:

> scripts.js:27 Uncaught TypeError:
>   document.getElementsByClassName(...).getElementsByTagName is not a
>   function
>       at HTMLDocument. (scripts.js:27)

¿Tendría que cambiar algo en esa línea o es que no se pueden combinar?

Comment: Saludos solo te falta colocar "[0]"..luego de getElementsByClassName('sidebar').. es decir "document.getElementsByClassName('sidebar')[0]...."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No se puede porque `getElementsByClassName` devuelve una `HTMLCollection` y este tipo de objeto no cuenta con la función `getlElementsByTagName` entre sus propiedades.

Para que se pueda podrías usar un bucle para iterar por cada uno de los elementos del `HTMLCollection`, por ejemplo

```
var enlacesSidebar = document.getElementByClassName('sidebar');
for(var i = 0; enlacesSidebar.length; i++){
  var anchorsSidebar = enlacesSidebar[i].getElementsByTagName('a');
  // lo que vayas a hacer con los anchors
}
```

Quizás en lugar de declarar la variable `anchorsSidebar` dentro del bucle y hacer la asignación, podrías crear un `Array` que donde pongas todos los elementos  del `HTMLCollection` resultado de `getElementsByTagName` pero eso dependerá de lo que quieras hacer con ellos.

Referencia

- [ElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo con [`GetElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) retorna un *objeto de tipo matriz* con todos los nodos del DOM que contienen dicha `class`, algo similar a esto:

```
[object HTMLCollection] {
  0: [object HTMLAnchorElement] {
    accessKey: "",
    addEventListener: function addEventListener() { [native code] },
    after: function after() { [native code] },
    animate: function animate() { [native code] },
    append: function append() { [native code] },
    appendChild: function appendChild() { [native code] },
    assignedSlot: null,
    attachShadow: function attachShadow() { [native code] },
    ATTRIBUTE_NODE: 2,
```

Donde como puedes observar es una colección con dichos nodos del árbol DOM, entonces si deseas acceder a dicho valor deberás indicar que elemento de la matriz de datos deseas obtener de este modo:

```
var enlacesSidebar = document.getElementsByClassName('sidebar')[0].getElementsByTagName('a');
```

> Donde 0 es el índice de la matriz que deseas recuperar y por ende obtener dicho valor. **(o iterarlos con un bucle como ya te recomiendan)**

En cambio hacer:

```
var enlacesSidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar')........
```

> Indica que va a recuperar un nodo del DOM apuntando directamente a aquel que sea identificado por el `id` escrito

Comment: Genial! Muchas gracias por tu explicación y muy buena tambien!